# Access Points with mismatching Passwords

Tags: networking, passwords, troubleshooting, wireless-access-point

I'm a Tech Coordinator at a local school and in the process of learning about the network at and help solve their problems.

I discovered that the upstairs access points have a different password than downstairs.

What effect does mismatched passwords have?

Can this influence Wi-Fi coverage?

All access points function and are working properly according to analytics but only one upstairs seems actually handling networking/devices.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You need to provide more details and perhaps better focus the question. As it stands right now it is too vague and broad.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the upstairs APs broadcast the same SSID (Wifi network name) as the downstairs ones it can cause indeed some issues. If their SSID is different there should be no issues.

While having different passwords for the same SSID will not cause physical interference (assuming they implemented a reasonable channel plan) it will still cause other issues.
For example it will causes problems when a device tries to roam from AP A with password A to AP B with password B.
The devices will fail to authenticate to AP B and depending on the OS/driver it might just fall back to the old AP but while doing so might still loose network connection for a short moment.
It could also maybe not fall back at all and instead nag the user about their password being wrong, loosing network access completely.

But even more importantly it can cause lots of confusion for you users. One moment they are having perfectly good Wifi downstairs and then suddenly when moving upstairs their connection will be terrible. (even though the Wifi might show up with good strength)
And if they get a message about their password being wrong they will very likely raise a ticket about why their access got revoked.
Also depending on the OS it might be kinda hard/annoying to delete the password. So if a user knows both passwords and wants to use both APs they will have to constantly delete the other one and enter the new one. (some devices might allow saving multiple passwords for the same SSID but that still won't work for roaming)

Ideally you should either change the upstair SSID to a different name or have the same password across all APs broadcasting the same SSID.

Answer (score 1):

All APs publishing the same network name (SSID) are expected to have the same wireless security type and the same wireless security passphrase. Clients treat all APs with the same SSID as interchangeable points of access to the same underlying network, and expect to be able to seamlessly roam between them. Having different wireless passphrases breaks that.

Many (most? all?) OSes will not let you save multiple passphrases for the same SSID. So clients that first joined the network using one passphrase will not automatically roam to the APs that use a different wireless security passphrase.

In your scenario, this means all the APs with the wrong wireless passphrase are failing to provide additional coverage, because your clients can't roam to them.